# Kullback-Leibler KLdiv permutation

Tags: r, distribution

my question refers to the R function `KLdiv` of the package `flexmix`. As far as I understood, permuting the input sample should not change the calculation, however it does. The following code snippet is an adaption of the example of the `KLdiv` help description.

```
require(flexmix)
x1 <- seq(-3, 3, length=200)
x2 <- sample(x1, replace=FALSE)
y <- cbind(x1, x2)
KLdiv(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss-understood permutation here. 
You should permute either the rows or the columns of the input object :

```
lapply(list(y[sample(nrow(y)),],y[,sample(ncol(y))]),KLdiv)
[[1]]
         x1       x2
x1 0.000000 5.356882
x2 5.588135 0.000000

[[2]]
         x1       x2
x1 0.000000 5.356882
x2 5.588135 0.000000
```

Result is the same for the 2 permutations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my intention of permuting is another. I try to explain here again. The function estimates this: **\int f(x) (\log f(x) - \log g(x)) dx**     And since permuting a sample does not change it's distribution function, nor it's density, I thought the result should stay the same.